# How to disable a NERDTree mapping that conflicts with a custom mapping?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I currently have this mapping in my .vimrc to make navigating between windows easier.

`nnoremap <c-j> <c-w>j`

I noticed that after installing NERDTree and opening it in the current buffer with `e .`, I couldn't use `c-j` anymore to move down to below window. I took a look at the NERDTree docs and found this mapping

`<C-J>...Jump down to the next sibling of the current directory...|NERDTree-C-J|`

I don't really see myself using this mapping, so how could I disable it and go back to `<c-j>` doing `<c-w>j`?

Comment: Wait, that means that you are loading your plugins (possibly with pathogen, vundle, ...) after your `noremap` in your .vimrc .  You should always perform plugin loading first, then your configuration, this prevents issues in both: plugins and configuration.  Also, we have http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Nope, my plugins were actually being loaded first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [NERDTree documentation](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt) (section `*NERDTree-C-J*`), this mapping is called `NERDTreeMapJumpNextSibling`.

In this case, you should set it to something else, so the plugin won't remap it.

Do this in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:NERDTreeMapJumpNextSibling = ''
```

Comment: I tried doing this and got
`No such variable: "g:NERDTreeMapJumpNextSibling"`

Comment: Also, wouldn't this just un set the variable but persist the mapping?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edited my answer. You should actually just map it to something else so the plugin don't try to map it to the default.

Comment: Ahh, that seemed to do it. Sorry if this is off topic, but why does reassigning the variable change the mapping when this fix occurs after the plugin loads?

Comment: Your `.vimrc` is loaded before the plugins, so you're actually *assigning* it. When NERDTree starts, it only creates the mapping if that variable doesn't exist. See [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/plugin/NERD_tree.vim#L37) and [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/plugin/NERD_tree.vim#L123).